# Grouping multiple VMs and their connectivity via Resource manager templates

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machines

I have a product, which is comprised of 2 VMs, (one linux and other freebsd), and they need to inter-connected via a private bridge on some network/subnet. Additionally, each may need more subnets connected to their NICs/interfaces. I saw there are Azure resource manager templates available in Azure - can they be used to define my product with multiple VMs, so that anyone using the json template can get the 2 VMs, their connectivity etc. defined in the template, and needs to only deploy the template to have my product come up? In some sense I need my VMs and the networking between them to come up as one object.
Thanjs
Anjali

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is yes, .Json templates can deploy both VMS and Vnets and configure them. There is documentation on Microsoft's web site:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-cli-deploy-templates

one thing you could do is create you Resource group, Vnets, Vms through the portal and then export the .json code that would be used to build the same resources. this is a great way to get the .json code you need and is a great learning tool.

to do this go create your resources in a resource group and then go to the resource groups properties > Automation Script section. you will see the code there and the export option.
[image]